# My swiper-pagination is overlapping with the text and my Hamburger appears behind the slider when open

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, swiper.js

i have a simple problem that i can't wrap my head around. My swiper-pagination that is supposed to appear at the bottom of the text overlaps with the text at the bottom of the page hence it cannot be seen clearly. I would like for it to appear like 10px below the text to clearly be seen by anyone visiting my site. Another problem is when you view it in mobile platform when you click on the hamburger the contents appear behind the slider and i would like then to appear in-front of the slider and be clickable for clients to view the other pages.My code is as follows below. If you seek more clarification please tell me and i will upload the additional details. Thanks in advance guys.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open');
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
            })
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SakaHapa</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <nav class="site-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home site-nav--icon"></i>HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o site-nav--icon"></i>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle site-nav--icon"></i>PROFILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus site-nav--icon"></i>PURCHASES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye site-nav--icon"></i>POPULAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope site-nav--icon"></i>CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off site-nav--icon"></i>Log Out</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h2>Slide man</h2>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                            when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen 
                            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                            typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the 
                            release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
                            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h2>Mafans</h2>
                        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable 
                            content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is 
                            that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 
                            'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop 
                            publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default 
                            model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in 
                            their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, 
                            sometimes on purpose.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
            </div>
            <!-- Add Pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div> 

            <script type="text/javascript" src="swiper.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
            <script>
                var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                    pagination: {
                        el: '.swiper-pagination',
                        clickable: true,
                        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
                            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
                        },
                    },
                });
            </script>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
body{
    background: #F0F8EA;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container{
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header{
    background: #E54B4B;
    color: #f8f4f4;
    padding: 1em 0;
    position: relative;
}
header::after{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.logo{
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.65em;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.logo ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.logo a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.logo a:hover,
.logo a:focus{
    color: #464655;
}
.navbar-nav{
    outline: none;
    float: right;
}
.navbar-nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar-nav a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 130%;
    right: .75em;
}
.navbar-nav a:hover,
.navbar-nav a:focus{
    color: #464655;
}

.site-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    background: #464655;
    clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
    transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
    /* display: none; */
}
.site-nav--open{
    clip-path: circle(100%);
}
.site-nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.site-nav li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
}
.site-nav li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.site-nav a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em 4.5em;    
    text-decoration: none;
}
.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus{
    background: #E4B363;
    color: #464655;
}
.site-nav--icon{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 0.7em;
    text-align: right;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}
.menu-toggle{
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: .75em;
    right: .75em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: #f8f4f4;
    height: 3px;
    width: 1.95em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}
.hamburger::before{
    transform: translateY(-7px);
}
.hamburger::after{
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
.open .hamburger{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.open .hamburger::before{
    opacity: 0;
}
.open .hamburger::after{
    transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}
@media (min-width: 1077px){
    .menu-toggle{
        display: none;
    }
    .site-nav{
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        background: transparent;
        float: right;
        clip-path: initial;
    }
    .site-nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
    }
    .site-nav a{
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 1.2em;
        font-size: 1.15em;
        padding-top: 7px;
    }
    .site-nav a:hover,
    .site-nav a:focus{
        background: transparent;
    }
    .site-nav li .fa{
        display: none;   
    }
}


.content-section{
    background: #f8f4f4;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #131212;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(15, 15, 15);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  div.form-group{
    margin-top: -24px;
  }
  .btn{
    background: rgb(41, 159, 180);
  }
  h5{
      color: #ffff;
  }
  h6{
     color: #ffff; 
  }
  .register{
    background: #dbd7d7;
  }


html, body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background: #eee;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #eee;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#000;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
    color: #000;
    background: #007aff;
}
```